Узнать все доступные команды на Minecraft сервере
Я создаю удобную консоль для Minecraft сервера через RCON, но также программа будет иметь доступ ко всему процессу сервера. Я хочу сделать функцию автозавершения команд, для этого мне нужен хотя бы список команд
["help","whitelist","op","kill",...]

Есть какой-нибудь API для получения списка всех команд сервера? Язык Java я не знаю, делаю всё на Python. Сервер запускается через мой лаунчер и предоставляет API для работы с stdin, stdout и stderr
На сервере могут быть плагины, может быть любое ядро. Тестирую на 1.20.4 Paper
